# Linux computer name for LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, redmine

today I tried to setup LDAP from linux server to AD system.
The connection can establish and login well.
But when I turn **logon to**  feature in AD (an user only can login from extract computer), I cannot use LDAP.

I use command

```
hostname
```

to show my linux computer and fill in AD. But it still fail to login.

If I change back to **all computer**, it runs well again.

So how to know the linux computer name to declare in AD.

Thank you

Comment: It depends on whether you've joined this Linux server to domain! If not, this will never work.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful  Do you mean, If I do not join this linux server to domain, it only work when I turn **off logon to** feature?

Comment: Yes, I meant the same. The AD DC doesn't identify the hostname, since the system is not joined to domain.

Comment: Can we manually add host name to AD?

Comment: Please find the answer to that part of **manually adding hostname in AD** here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c173d064-91f4-4fab-a2fb-1157c364ecd2/manually-create-a-computer-account-in-ad-before-join-it-to-ad?forum=winserverDS